# reading value from registry and storing it in a bin file

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# module; and I need to retrieve the value of a key called 'LicenseKey' from the registry path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Avtec, Inc/LicenseKey' and store the value in a bin file called "pml.bin"

I have some problems with the code. Can anyone help me with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code you are having problems with?

Comment: Not seeing a screenshot attached to this. Can you also post the code for that matter?

Comment: pls check d link here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738554/reading-value-from-registry-and-storing-it-in-a-bin-file-in-a-folder

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with the below code and not facing any issues. Check the registry path and ensure proper slashes "\" in the path. Check the below code with your code,

```
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
        RegistryKey dataKey = key.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Avtec.Inc\LicenseKey");
        string licenceKey = dataKey.GetValue("required field name").ToString();

        using (BinaryWriter b = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Create)))
        {
            b.Write(licenceKey);
            b.Close();
        }
```