# reading value from registry and storing it in a bin file in a folder

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# code. As shown in the image, I need to retrieve the value of a key called `LicenseKey` (right side of the image) from the registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Avtec, Inc/LicenseKey` and store the value in a bin file called `pml.bin`

Can anyone help me with the code? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: We won't write code for you, this is not the purpose of this website.

Comment: @harish please try google search first for 'C# read registry' and then if you encounter problems then ask questions, it will help you find solutions on your own first :)

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to Microsoft.Win32 API and add the below code.

```
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
        RegistryKey dataKey = key.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Avtec.Inc\LicenseKey");
        string licenceKey = dataKey.GetValue("required field name").ToString();

        using (BinaryWriter b = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Create)))
        {
            b.Write(licenceKey);
            b.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Try to avoid asking or posting your requirements. Do a initial research and give a try, if u are facing any issues in that, then post here. You will get a help here for sure...